# Extract usernames from emails in R

Tags: r, data-cleaning

How Can I extract usernames from these emails in R ? For example : `<Angelwgsx2@aol.com>` to `Angelwgsx2`.

```
<Angelwgsx2@aol.com>, <Jason.Bass2@COMPAQ.com>, <alaska_turtles@yahoo.com>, <Vettel22@flash.net>, <Blondi46@aol.com>, <ccoffee@anpower.com>, <cassiecorcoran@hotmail.com>, <charityp@flash.net>, <moonriter1@aol.com>, <ckendal@comp.uark.edu>, <delena38@home.com>, <deniesed@hotmail.com>, <dndlitch@btigate.com>, <Eric.Bass>, <marstersco@earthlink.net>, <whmfgm@yahoo.com>, <starlit_gazer@yahoo.com>, <Ggstops@aol.com>, <greenup@airmail.net>, <jimmycheer@yahoo.com>, <hmcgill-satx@worldnet.att.net>, <janet.corcoran@verizon.com>, <strait_line@yahoo.com>, <wxranch@airmail.net>, <jayjayjarv@yahoo.com>, <jwheeler45@home.com>,
```

Comment: `sub("<([A-z0-9\\._]+)@.*>", "\\1", c("<Angelwgsx2@aol.com>", "<Jason.Bass2@COMPAQ.com>", "<alaska_turtles@yahoo.com>", "<Vettel22@flash.net>"))`

Comment: @waterling thank you